# Cancel async API call from useEffect on unmount

Tags: reactjs

I've got the API call as soon as the page loads in a `useEffect` hook, can I somehow cancel the request if the component unmounts?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const callContract = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        //  ... call API here
      } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    callContract();
  }, []);
```

Comment: `useEffect` can certainly return a cleanup callback (read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup), does whatever's making your requests have a way of cancelling that request (e.g. https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation)?

Answer (score -1):

The `useEffect` return value is the unmount function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("I got mounted");

  return () => {
    console.log("I got unmounted");
  };
}, []);
```